# Have different names in class field and bound form input with Spring forms?

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

Does anyone know if it is possible, using automatic Spring databinding with  tags, to have the form name be different from the class/object field it is bound to?

I am working on a system where, by convention, parameters passed through GET and POST have a prefix. That prefix doesn't jibe all that well with Java conventions as to class and field names.

Hibernate, for instance, allows custom naming of tables and columns that hold object data.

Is there something similar, an annotation perhaps, that works this way for forms?
I'm thinking of something like this:

```
@FormInputName(value = "pre_firstName") private String firstName;
```

And then in my JSP:

```
<form:input path="pre_firstName"/>
```

Comment: why would you want to do this ? It currently follows the bean spec, what benefit is there not to.

Comment: As I mentioned: naming conventions between Java and the CMS it works with in this case are rather different. As such, I would like to do this to maintain good hygiene.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@RequestParam(value="form_field_name")` like this:

```
@RequestParam(value = "pre_firstName") private String firstName;
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html